# Trying to track down a bizarre superhero comic involving gifted children who reunite in adulthood at their father's funeral

Tags: story-identification, comics

I 95% feel like I came upon this series on this site, but I can't seem to locate it. The basic idea behind the strip is that a scientist/adventurer man has died at the beginning of the strip, and his children (I'm not certain if they were natural or adopted) are coming to his funeral. There's bad blood between them, although I don't entirely remember why. They all had different superpowers. I believe one was an astronaut who may have also been a nonhuman primate (an ape or gorilla?). There was a boy who never aged, and might have had mental powers, at least one girl (I don't remember what powers), and a boy who had some sort of time-travel powers. I remember that one of them always carried an umbrella (a white one?) although I don't remember why.

In the course of the comic, we learn that they used to act as superheroes under the guidance of their father until something happened to cause them to part ways. In the course of events, I think they reveal that the father is not as dead as they thought, and there's something involving the time-travel powers and a dystopian future (in retrospect, the boy with time powers might have also been the one who didn't age).

The art style was stark and used few colors. Didn't look like manga, and was not realistic. For some reason, I want to say it was a British series.

I read this somewhere around 2010-2015 as a trade paperback from the library (and yes, my library tracks what I check out, but I haven't had much luck combing through it). It was in English. That's all that's coming to mind right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [*The Umbrella Academy: Apocalypse Suite*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Umbrella_Academy:_Apocalypse_Suite)

I remember this exactly, as it is one of my favourites. It's weird and dark and distinctive, and that's why I love it.

> In Apocalypse Suite, the team disbanded and failed to stay in contact with each other until they were reunited upon the news of Hargreeves' death, and subsequently reformed the team after one of their own number became a supervillain.

It has everything you recalled:

The gorilla was the butler for the mansion the group lived in as children.

The boy who never aged had time travel powers, with the exception he could only travel forwards in time. He travels into the future to see it destroyed by an apocalypse, and spends his subplot trying to find a way back in time to stop the Earth getting destroyed (this isn't the main story of the book though).

The main story is the rest of the group fighting against a former member who is trying to cause the apocalypse (the supervillain mentioned in the quote).

Comment: Thank you. And it doesn't seem this did come up here... I guess it has now!

Comment: Nicely done, I thought I’d nab this one

Comment: This is now a series on--either Netflix or Amazon prime.  They did a good job with it.